# Adding an unknown number of objects to an arraylist

Tags: java, object, arraylist

i have a school assignment which requires me to add an unknown number of instances of a class "fruit" in to an arraylist "basket" and print out the details of each fruit object, my code adds the fruits to the arraylist but seems to override the previous entry each time leaving me with an arraylist of the same project. This is my code so far:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Question1
{
   public static void main(String[]Augs)
   {
      List<Fruit> basket = new ArrayList<Fruit>();
      int input;
      Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
      String name;
      String colour;
      double mass;
      int k = -1;
      while (true)
      {
         System.out.println("Enter option: (1) add fruit (2) quit:");
         input = inp.nextInt();
         if (input==2)
            break;
         else
         {
             k++;
            System.out.println("Enter name, colour and mass in kg separated by space");
            name = inp.next();
            colour = inp.next();
            mass = inp.nextDouble();
            Fruit temp = new Fruit(name, colour, mass);
            basket.add(temp);
         }
      }
      for (int i = 0; i<basket.size(); i++)
      {
         System.out.println(basket.get(i));
      }
   }
}

//fruit class
public class Fruit
{
   private String name;
   private String colour;
   private double mass;
   public Fruit(String name, String colour, double mass)
   {
      this.name=name;
      this.colour=colour;
      this.mass=mass;
   }
   public String toString()
   {
      return name + " " + colour + " " + mass;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks just fine in terms of adding the fruits to the basket. I think what's getting you is `System.out.println(basket.get(i))`. You are essentially asking a `Fruit` object to be printed, but the run time does not know how to do that and as such tries to convert the `Fruit` to some String representation by calling the `toString()` method on it. I think your `Fruit` class prints the same String no matter what's inside it. Try overriding the `toString()` method to get the correct results.

```
public class Fruit
{
    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return this.getName() + " " + this.getColor() + " " + this.getMass();
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention it but I do have a toString method that overides the default

Comment: ah, I see my problem now, I had set my variables as public static for some odd reason, thank you. And if I wanted to go further and sort my list first by alphabetical order on the name, then by
colour, then by mass (ascending order) how would i go about it?

Comment: Look into http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2784514/sort-arraylist-of-custom-objects-by-property for sorting.